# Concatenating two XYSeries in JFreeChart

Tags: jfreechart

I'm using JFreeGraph API to plot real time graphs for read/write operations. To give real time feel i update the graph for every 1000 updates; with one XYSeries already added to dataset. So as new update comes, series updates itself as
xySeries.addOrUpdate(int, int);

Currently I'm using only one series which doesn't let me add or update in nonUI thread and in case of UI thread, rest of the access gets blocked. So I was wondering if i could work on temp series in nonUI thread and only in case of update use UI thread. 
Is there any way I can update temp series and then add it into xySeries in UI thread?
Something like, concatenating of 2 xySeries?

Please share if there are any other work around, solutions, etc.

Thanks,
Vrushali

Comment: You might be able to use one of the approaches shown in [Using `JFreeChart` to display recent changes in a time series](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852/using-jfreechart-to-display-recent-changes-in-a-time-series).

Comment: THanks for your reply. Is there any way i can modify series offline and then update? my series is already linked with dataset. I need a way to update series offline without making actual change in graph and then fire update after certain interval.

Answer (score 1):

From [`XYSeries`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeries.html), chose an `add()` method that allows you to specify a value for `notify`, setting it to `true` only *after* you want to the notification to occur. The actual implementation will depend on your sorting and duplicate value requirements. Providing an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) may be helpful.